# Python flask writing to a csv file and reading it

Tags: python, html, forms, csv, flask

I can read from the CSV file but I'm unsure as to how I can write to it.

The idea is to have allow the user to enter their comment and it save on the CSV file and then further print out the comment

This is the code for reading for reading the csv file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask import request
import csv

def comments():
    with open('static\\comments.csv', 'r') as inFile: 
        reader = csv.reader(inFile)
        commentsList = [row for row in reader]
```

Here is the code that I am using to display the fields within the csv file. I want to use the form to somehow add fields to the given csv file

```html
<table border="1">
    {% for line in commentsList %}
    <tr>
    {% for item in line%}
    <td>
    {{item}}
    </td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    </div>
    <form action="addToComments" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="username">
    Comment: <input type="text" name="comment">
    Date: <input type="date" name="date">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a handy solution:

```
>>> import pyexcel as pe
>>> a=[["someone", "good one", "01/Dec/14"]]
>>> sheet = pe.Sheet(a)
>>> sheet
Sheet Name: pyexcel
+---------+----------+-----------+
| someone | good one | 01/Dec/14 |
+---------+----------+-----------+
>>> sheet.colnames=["username", "comment", "date"]
>>> sheet
Sheet Name: pyexcel
+----------+----------+-----------+
| username | comment  |   date    |
+==========+==========+===========+
| someone  | good one | 01/Dec/14 |
+----------+----------+-----------+
>>> sheet.save_as("comments.csv")
>>> exit()

$ cat comments.csv
username,comment,date
someone,good one,01/Dec/14
```

If you will need to read the csv file from file:

```
>>> import pyexcel as pe
>>> sheet = pe.load("comments.csv", name_columns_by_row=0)
>>> sheet
Sheet Name: csv
+----------+----------+-----------+
| username | comment  |   date    |
+==========+==========+===========+
| someone  | good one | 01/Dec/14 |
+----------+----------+-----------+
```

And here's an example on [how to handle upload and download using Flask and pyexcel](https://github.com/chfw/pyexcel/blob/master/examples/memoryfile/pyexcel_server.py).

An update on 25/Feb/2015: you may also have a look at my plugin: [Flask-Excel](https://github.com/chfw/Flask-Excel)

Answer (score 2):

You can just append a line to the csv file.

Just get the fields from the POST request and append it to the file.

```
s = ",".join([username, comment, date])

fd = open("path/to/file.csv", "a")
fd.write(s)
fd.close()
```

Opening the file in `a` mode will position the stream at the end of the file.

UPDATE: Created an example for you.

```
from flask import url_for

@app.route("/add-comment/", methods=["POST"])
def add_comment():
    username = request.form["username"]
    comment = request.form["comment"]
    date = request.form["date"]

    f = open('static\\comments.csv', 'a')
    f.write(",".join([username, comment, date])
    f.close()

    return redirect(url_for('comments'))
```

And in your template set the form action to the correct URL

`<form action="/add-comment/" method="post">`

I am not used to flask so it might not be correct

Comment: @LukeGarrigan Have you set up some routing? Can you show more code in your question? Do you know how to handle a POST request in Flask?

Comment: @LukeGarrigan I have added some more code to show you how you can do some basic routing.